# How do I add comments to buddypress forum replies

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I'm setting up a custom buddypress install and would like to have comments directly on the forum topics page. I see that its possible to show your forum replies on the group activity stream, but I would like to have it the other way around. I essentially post a question as the "Topic" let everyone answer that question in their replies, but I'd like to see people comment on other peoples answers.

Answer (score 0):

We're working on the same problem right now, this is what I suggested to my development team -

> we can directly replicate the comments functionality that comes with
>   wordpress and database schema for wp_comments table. Like each topic
>   post can be like a blog post with comments. Above action hook will help with fetching and display.

Comment: I ended up using the bbpress-threaded replies plugin which works well as a commenting system on topic replies. This post happened prior to a major update of bbpress which offered a full featured bbpress blog to be linked to groups. If anyone is confused take a look at: http://codex.buddypress.org/user/setting-up-a-new-installation/installing-group-and-sitewide-forums/

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same feature on Buddypress forum posts and finally got the success with the only available plugin bbPress Threaded Replies. This plugin added the same comment and reply system to my buddypress-bbpress forum posts as it is for my general sitewide activity.

If you need, you can download and install teh same at http://wordpress.org/plugins/bbpress-threaded-replies/